# Advanced PHP url getting

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okay, so I have two pages, home.php and page.php. On home.php, I load page.php onto it using jquery. In the url of home.php there is a GET value, u. I want to access that GET value on page.php. You can see that I tried the regular $_GET method, but this does not work. If on page.php I can just get the url of home.php with the GET variables in the url, I can get the info from there. But right now I cannot get the url of home.php, it just gets page.php. I hope that makes sense and thanks for the help!

Home.php

```
<div id='holder'></div>
<script>
  $('#holder').load('page.php');
</script>
```

Page.php

```
<?php
   $u = $_GET['u'];
   echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // echo's "page.php". I need it to echo "home.php?u=test"
   //some php

?>
```

Comment: `.load('page.php?u=foo')`? there's nothing magical about this - load() expects a url, and that url can have query parameters.

Comment: This might work. But the "u" will be different sometimes, but I think I can find a way to make it work. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass the $_GET variable to the requested page.
Do it like this:

```
<div id='holder'></div>
<script>
  $('#holder').load('page.php<?php echo "?u=" . $_GET[" u" ]; ?>');
</script>
```

Stackoverflow doesn't parse it the way I want but I'm  sure it works.